# 'Error: base fee exceeds gas limit' When creating new contract instance (Using Truffle, Web3Js and testrpc)

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, testrpc

I have the following code in `app.js` file of my truffle project.

```
import { default as Web3} from 'web3';
import { default as contract } from 'truffle-contract'
import conferrence_artifacts from '../../build/contracts/Conferrence.json'

var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

// Conferrence is our usuable abstraction, which we'll use through the code below.
var Conferrence = contract(conferrence_artifacts);
Conferrence.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);

var accounts = web3.eth.accounts;
var account = accounts[0];
Conferrence.new({from: account}).then(function(instance){
   console.log(instance);
});
```

As provided in the documentation [Truffle add new contract](http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/contracts#add-a-new-contract-to-the-network)

*Note: In the call to Conferrence.new({from: account})... **{from: account}** was used because I was getting 'invalid address error'*

**Console Error Log**

```
Error: Error: base fee exceeds gas limit
    at runCall (C:\Users\Devendra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\node_modules\ethereumjs-vm\lib\runTx.js:111:17)
    at C:\Users\Devendra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\node_modules\ethereumjs-vm\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3686:9
    at replenish (C:\Users\Devendra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\node_modules\ethereumjs-vm\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:881:17)
    at iterateeCallback (C:\Users\Devendra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\node_modules\ethereumjs-vm\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:866:17)
    at C:\Users\Devendra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\node_modules\ethereumjs-vm\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:843:16
    at C:\Users\Devendra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\node_modules\ethereumjs-vm\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3691:13
    at apply (C:\Users\Devendra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\node_modules\ethereumjs-vm\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:21:25)
    at C:\Users\Devendra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\node_modules\ethereumjs-vm\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:56:12
    at Object.async.eachSeries (C:\Users\Devendra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\node_modules\async-eventemitter\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:130:20)
    at VM.AsyncEventEmitter.emit (C:\Users\Devendra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\node_modules\async-eventemitter\lib\AsyncEventEmitter.js:42:9)
    at runCall (C:\Users\Devendra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\node_modules\ethereumjs-vm\lib\runTx.js:111:17)
    at C:\Users\Devendra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\node_modules\ethereumjs-vm\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3686:9
    at replenish (C:\Users\Devendra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\node_modules\ethereumjs-vm\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:881:17)
    at iterateeCallback (C:\Users\Devendra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\node_modules\ethereumjs-vm\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:866:17)
    at C:\Users\Devendra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\node_modules\ethereumjs-vm\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:843:16
    at C:\Users\Devendra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\node_modules\ethereumjs-vm\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3691:13
    at apply (C:\Users\Devendra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\node_modules\ethereumjs-vm\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:21:25)
    at C:\Users\Devendra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\node_modules\ethereumjs-vm\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:56:12
    at Object.async.eachSeries (C:\Users\Devendra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\node_modules\async-eventemitter\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:130:20)
    at VM.AsyncEventEmitter.emit (C:\Users\Devendra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\node_modules\async-eventemitter\lib\AsyncEventEmitter.js:42:9)
    at Object.InvalidResponse (http://localhost:8080/app.js:8374:16)
    at http://localhost:8080/app.js:32995:36
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (http://localhost:8080/app.js:35321:13)
```

But this works absolutely fine when executing in truffle console -

```
truffle(development)> Conferrence.new().then(function(ins){console.log(ins.address)})
0x7e796caed4202ae58bb58afc214f281969f995b2
```

NVM about the 'Conferrence' typo :p

Comment: Truffle sucks. I solved it and now can run mocha ganache tests without truffle. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/46957/solidity-exceeds-block-gas-limit-during-mocha-tests-with-ganache-cli

Answer (score 10):

Since your example code uses **truffle-contract** you can [specify the default values](https://www.npmjs.com/package/truffle-contract#mycontractdefaultsnew_defaults) for your transactions and contract deployments like this (*Conferrence* is the name of your contract. I used the truffle default values):

```
Conferrence.defaults({
  from: account,
  gas: 4712388,
  gasPrice: 100000000000
})
```

I had the same problem (`base fee exceeds gas limit`) and [browser-solidity](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity) gave me a `Gas requirement of function xyz.sol:Xyz.doSomething(address) unknown or not constant.` Specifying default values helped eventually.

Answer (score 7):

When running your code in the Truffle console, it will ensure that certain defaults have been set:

> For each network, if unspecified, transaction options will default to the following values:
>
> - gas: Gas limit used for deploys. Default is 4712388.
> - gasPrice: Gas price used for deploys. Default is 100000000000 (100 Shannon).
> - from: From address used during migrations. Defaults to the first available account provided by your Ethereum client.

(from http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration#networks)

But when you're running in a different environment, such as in a browser, then those defaults will not be available and you'll have to specify them for each transaction. In your case that means not only providing `from` but also `gas`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to increase the amount of gas you're willing to pay for the contract creation. For example:

```
Conferrence.new({from: account, gas: SOME AMOUNT HERE});
```

Basically the anticipated cost of the transaction is greater than the amount you are providing by default.  So you need to bump up the gas in your call to `new`.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue and I believe people are getting confused about what the gas parameter actually means in truffle.js file.

I answered my own question here. Hope it helps.

[Truffle contract deployment either exceeds block gas limit or out of gas](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/59485/truffle-contract-deployment-either-exceeds-block-gas-limit-or-out-of-gas/59486#59486)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not related to this question exactly, but I trope with the same error when executing `truffle test` for a solidity contract and the gas error given was misleading. You could translate it as 'Unknown error at deployment'. In my case, I could get the real error by running `truffle deploy --reset`.