# Could somebody please explain in detail what this Ethereum contract is doing?

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, blockchain, truffle, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I am new to ethereum & blockchain technology and trying to understand somethings(Etheruem, Truffle, DApps etc.) here and there from the internet.
From Ethereum official website,

> [Create a cryptocurrency contract in Ethereum](https://www.ethereum.org/token#the-code)

I am trying to specifically understand these functions

`approve(address _spender, uint _value) returns (bool success) {...}`

`approveAndCall(address _spender, uint _value, bytes _extraData) returns (bool success) {...}`

`transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint _value) returns (bool success) {...}`

and lastly this `function() {throw;}`

This contract code

```
contract tokenRecipient {
  function receiveApproval(address _from, uint _value, address _token, bytes _extraData);
}
```

and this declaration `mapping (address => mapping (address => uint) ) public allowance;`

Comment: The is a example showing how the token `transfer(...)`, `approve(...)` and `transferFrom(...)` functions work at https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard#How_Does_A_Token_Contract_Work.3F .

Comment: @BokkyPooBah Thanks for the link. Understood it better.

Answer (score 9):

`approve(address _spender, uint _value) returns (bool success) {...}`
 This function is just being used to make an entry to the allowance array when another contract want to spend some tokens. _ spender is the address of the contract which is going to use it. _value denotes the number of tokens to be spend.
`approveAndCall(address _spender, uint _value, bytes _extraData) returns (bool success) {...}`
if `approve()` function returns true, it will invoke the `receiveApproval()` function of contract `tokenRecipient`.
`transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint _value) returns (bool success) {...}`
 This function will be used to transfer tokens from one address to another. Variables are self-explanatory.
`function() {throw;}`
 This is fallback function. According to its functionality, this function will be executed when someone tries to send the ether to the contract. `throw;` prevents accidental sending of ether.
`contract tokenRecipient {
  function receiveApproval(address _from, uint _value, address _token, bytes _extraData);
}`
This tells the `MyToken` contract that the function `receiveApproval` of contract `tokenRecipient` can be invoked somewhere in this code.
`mapping (address => mapping (address => uint) ) public allowance;`
 And lastly this line is a way to declare an array by defining the type of key and value. Value further can contain an array. You can assume it a 2D array. This is being used here to keep the record of users asking for the approval of spending the token for the other contracts.
This contract is ERC20-compliant as it implements the approve(...), transfer(..) and transferFrom(...) functions. 
For more detail : https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard#How_Does_A_Token_Contract_Work.3F

Comment: I think the answer would be improved if you mentioned that the `approve`, `transfer` and `transferFrom` functions are part of the ERC 20 token standard. That's a very important thing to note, I think.

Comment: Could somebody help me with http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12848/error-base-fee-exceeds-gas-limit-when-creating-new-contract-instance-using-t doubt of mine?

Comment: can you explain the `bytes _extraData` parameter from approveAndCall ?

Comment: That is an optional data that you can send to the contract who is being approved as a spender of token.